# Assembly 8086- Pushing and popping registers from stack not working

Tags: assembly, x86-16, qemu

I am a beginner and pushing and popping off the stack isn't working for me for some reason. My bootloader:

```
org 0x7c00
bits 16
jmp main
print:
    pop bx
    mov al, [bx]
    mov ah, 0eh
    int 10h
    ret
main:
    mov bx, msg
    push bx
    call print

    cli
    hlt

    msg: db 'Hello World!', 0
    times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
    dw 0xAA55
```

What this should do is, I believe, push the address `msg` onto the stack from `bx` and then retrieve it into `bx`. However, that does not seem to be the case. `'H'` does not get printed. A `'-'` is printed instead. It works if I use `msg` as the effective address.

**Edit**: As Duncan pointed out, the `call` instruction was pushing the return address at the top of my stack which made the above program use that return address for the BIOS interrupt! I now `pop` the return address into `dx` then `pop` into `bx`, use the value of `bx` and `jmp` to `dx` after I am done!

```
org 0x7c00
bits 16
jmp main
print:
    pop dx
    pop bx
    mov al, [bx]
    mov ah, 0eh
    int 10h
    jmp dx
main:
    mov bx, msg
    push bx
    call print

    cli
    hlt

    msg: db 'Hello World!', 0
    times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
    dw 0xAA55
```

Comment: Of course then there's the question of whether `dx` is preserved over the `int 10h` call.

Comment: That "fix" is unreasonably complex IMO. And fragile.. if anything, you can do `push dx` right after `pop bx` and use `ret` then, so you don't need to worry about `dx`, but if you insist on passing arguments through stack, you should rather do the verbose `push bp` `mov bp,sp` naive-C stack frame thing (and then `mov bx,[bp+4]` is first argument), as that will be easy to read for any somewhat experienced ASM programmer, so it will be easier to help you later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `call` instruction pushes the program counter onto the stack, and `ret` pops the top value from the stack and jumps to it.

So you cannot pass parameters to a function by pushing them before the call and popping them inside the call as the saved pc will get in the way.

Options might include setting up a frame pointer so you can access parameters which are still on the stack, and then pop them as part of the return.

Or for something this simple you could pop the return address into another register and instead of returning you just jump to it.

Comment: If you know the length of the return address, and/or other pushed values, you can address them directly, EG: `mov bx,2[sp]`

Comment: Is that a good practice in languages like assembly? I come from an OOP background.

Comment: @ArjavGarg it's good practice to have learned assembly basics first before trying to write something as tricky as bootloader, where you fight against the very hostile environment since the start (very fuzzy and buggy initial state as BIOS vendors don't care too much, plus almost no services available to be called, except the BIOS services). I'm still confused what is so appealing about writing own bootloader or even bare metal OS, instead of using some stable OS environment to write some fun stuff like playing with some graphics and having GUI debuggers available. OS-dev is just more tricky.

Comment: I've already done a OpenGL and 2d Java graphics. This seems to be the next logical step

Comment: @ArjavGarg the next logical step to me sounds like doing OGL + 2D in assembly then, as you already know the principles, and can focus on learning the assembly itself, get familiar with basic instructions, arithmetic, memory management, stack usage, etc... then again bootloader (at least initial part) has to be in 16b real mode, which is another PITA, so ... yeah, it doesn't matter, if you want to do bootloader, it's fine, just don't expect it to be easy, it will bite you and backfire many more times than any Java could, requiring much more attention to details and micromanaging *everything*.

Comment: This specific "bootloader" seems easier to do than OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

Start by `jmp far 0:main`, to normalize `cs:ip`, as some BIOS will call you with `cs=0`, and some with `cs=0x07c0`.

```
print:
    pop bx
    mov al, [bx]
    mov ah, 0eh
    int 10h
    ret
```

Maybe you have seen something like this in shell exploits, but the correct usage then looks like this:

```
    call print  ; this will put `msg` at top of stack!
msg: db 'H'
print:
    pop bx      ; load `msg` address
    ... no RET !! (there's nowhere to return to)
```

That's a trick how to put correct offset into stack when you don't know where your code will be located (shell exploit lands usually into some buffer overflow area, with some randomized address).

That's not needed in bootloader, as you are at fixed position `0000:7C00` and you can assemble as that, so using some custom "pass argument value by register" calling convention for custom procedures like `print` is fine, without involving stack at all (except using it to store return address by the `call + ret` pair).

---

Also initialize the stack before using it, i.e. at the beginning of main you may want to do for example:

```
main:
    ; set ss:sp to 0000:7C00 (so you have about ~29kB of RAM for stack)
    xor ax,ax
    mov ss,ax       ; disables interrupts for 1 more instruction
    mov sp,0x7C00   ; so sp set must follow the `ss` setup
```

Don't use it for any deep recursion of course, 29kB is small stack (yet plenty for reasonably written bootloader, loading just some kernel from disk, actually 100-200B of stack should be enough for that).

And set up `ds` of course! As you do `mov al,[bx]` like the `ds` was already set. In your case the easiest thing is to keep everything at `0000:7C00`, so ahead of `mov ss,ax` you can do `mov ds,ax` as well.

Comment: @ArjavGarg Spend few weeks at http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page reading + experimenting with other sources. You may even want to read sources of `grub`, which has to work in real-world scenarios. I never did bootloader myself, too boring for me, I prefer real app coding, so I'm not aware of ALL possible problems with writing bootloader, but it's certainly not possible to fit them into somewhat short answer, as it would be at least tens of pages of text. What you have may work already under qemu or bochs, and I think both options can be debugged somehow? Bochs for sure.